# Detecting DataTimeZone

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to automatically detect visitors timezone so the date and time displayed reflects their current time. I realize this isn't possible with PHP alone but will need some JavaScript as well.

**What can I use to replace the value of `$timezone` in the code below to automatically detect a visitors timezone?**

```
<?php

// Date & time format.
$date_format = "m/d/Y";
$time_format = "h:i A";
$timezone = "America/New_York";

// Get current datetime.
$date = new DateTime();

// Set timezone.
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($timezone));

// Echo current date and time.
echo $date->format($date_format . " " . $time_format);

?>
```

Returns:

```
07/22/2014 03:03 PM
```

Comment: Use `getTimezoneOffset()` in JavaScript to get the user's timezone

Comment: As you said you can't do this with PHP as it is a server side language. You will need to use javaascript and then do an ajax post to your server.

Comment: I'm not to great with JavaScript or AJAX. Could you help me modify the code so it will work with JS?

Comment: You will need to show some effort first. Write some code both the javascript side and the php and if you have problems then come ask the SO community for help.

Answer (score 2):

Using java script you can use it

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js'></script>
<script src="https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/raw/f9e3e30e1e1f53dd27cd0f73eb51a7e7caf7b378/jstz.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 var timezone = jstz.determine();
 $("#div").html(timezone.name());
});
</script>
<div id='div'></div>
```

Remember that download jstz.min.js  it doesn't allow embed from https://bitbucket.org/
if you want  see it working giv one look at 
http://gomusic.designerbh.com/teste.php

Comment: I was actually looking at that earlier, but I couldn't figure out how to import the value into PHP. My JS skills aren't very good, I'm primarily a HTML/CSS and PHP/MySQL developer.

Comment: use the $.post() of jquery

Comment: Still cant seem to figure it out. Been googling it for half hour trying to find a guide to doing it but can't find anything. I don't do JS or AJAX coding, but I can edit scripts.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){ var timezone = jstz.determine();$.post('yourpage.php',timezone:timezone,function(rt){ $("#div").html(rt);});});  replace yourpage.php with the url to your page the contais the script and make an div with id='div' any problen email-me info@designerbh.com

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to use Javascript

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/28Tgz/61/) for an example

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var foo = jQuery('#foo');

    function updateTime() {
        var now = new Date(),
            d = [];

        d[0] = now.getFullYear().toString(),
        d[1] = now.getMonth()+1, //months are 0-based
        d[2] = now.getDate(),
        d[3] = now.getHours(),
        d[4] = now.getMinutes();

        //doing YY manually as getYear() is deprecated
        //remove the next line if you want YYYY instead of YY
        d[0] = d[0].substring(d[0].length-2); //not using substr(-2) as it doesn't work in IE

        //leading zeroes
        for (var i=1; i<=4; i++)
            if (d[i] < 10) d[i] = '0' + d[i];

        foo.val(d[0] + '-' + d[1] + '-' + d[2] + ' ' + d[3] + ':' + d[4]);
    }

    updateTime();
    setInterval(updateTime, 5000); // 5 * 1000 miliseconds
});
```

Comment: Could you please provide the relevant info in your answer? That way when the links die your answer would still be valid.

Comment: I changed answer to something more robust.

Comment: I need to get a CURRENT time and store it to a MySQL in the format of a timestamp. This is easily done with PHP. The problem is then translating that timestamp to reflect the users timezone.

Comment: I updated http://jsfiddle.net/28Tgz/766/ to show the full current time. You can also use AJAX to send the variable to MYSQL (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545351/using-ajax-to-send-lat-lng-variables-to-php-for-proximity-calculation for an example)